# Creating a Colormap Legend in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `imshow()` in matplotlib like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mat = '''SOME MATRIX'''
plt.imshow(mat, origin="lower", cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

How do I add a legend showing the numeric value for the different shades of gray. Sadly, my googling has not uncovered an answer :(

Thank you in advance for the help.

Vince

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Simple, just [`plt.colorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mat = np.random.random((10,10))
plt.imshow(mat, origin="lower", cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 44):

There's a builtin [colorbar() function](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) in pyplot.  Here's an example using subplots:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plot = ax.pcolor(data)
fig.colorbar(plot)
```

Comment: If you're using subplots, you may need to use it like `fig = plt.figure(); ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1); plot = ax.pcolor(data); fig.colorbar(plot);`

Comment: Code example(s) would've been nice; I thought protocol was link-only answers are considered poor.  Easiest use is just `plt.colorbar()`

Comment: @CarlG Yassss this is SO at its best. Real answer in the comments.

Comment:  Funny coincidence that I made that comment exactly four years ago!  Haha.

Comment: pyplot.savefig('image.tiff') or pyplot.savefig('image.png') for saving it

Answer (score 9):

As usual, I figure it out right after I ask it ;). For posterity, here's my stab at it:

```
m = np.zeros((1,20))
for i in range(20):
    m[0,i] = (i*5)/100.0
print m
plt.imshow(m, cmap='gray', aspect=2)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,25,5), [0,25,50,75,100])
plt.show()
```

I'm sure there exists a more elegant solution.

Vince

Comment: +Plus 1 for " I figure it out right after I ask it , for posterity". I am also on the page as Vince. Phrasing a question helps to find an answer, and I also found finding it myself after writing in SO. Thanks for leaving for posterity, I appreciate this attitude!